# Is it possible to get a visa at the France embassy in Washington for NYC residents?

Tags: schengen-visas

I'm trying to book an appointment iat the France consulate in NYC but it’s all booked up. I bought the tickets for the end of July and I'm now afraid I can't get a visa. Is it possible to go to the French Embassy in Washington to get a visa, because they have some spots for an appointment? i appreciate your answer.

Comment: @MikeHarris: The question is not whether she can physically get to the embassy in Washington, but whether they will process her application if she's not resident in their consular service area.

Comment: +1 @MikeHarris that's an answer, add and I'll upvote.

Comment: @Giorgio: I on the other hand would downvote since it wouldn't address the real problem.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, you're right, of course; one would have to reside in the consular jurisdiction to be allowed to submit  at the Washington VFS Centre.

Comment: @Giorgio I assumed the French embassy in DC would cover the entire country, but I did some research and that's apparently not the case. I've added an answer below.

Comment: @HenningMakholm excellent points, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to [france-visas](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en_US/web/us/a-qui-sadresser), the VFS Global center in Washington DC only processes visa applications for residents of DC, MD, PA, VA, and WV. As a NY resident, you are requested to use the NYC consulate.

However, if you are unable to make an appointment in NYC and you can get one in DC, it might be worth speaking with someone in the embassy to see if it will be permitted. But officially, the answer is "no."

**Edit:**

I noticed that the france-visas website makes a distinction between the **VFS Global center in Washington DC** and the **Consulate general of France in Washington,** with two separate links for appointments. It's *possible* that the DC consulate handles visa requests for the entire country (and emergency cases). I recommend you contact them directly and explain your situation.